# Facebook sdk not found when run the project on another computer

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-4.0

I added the facebook SDK and build successful into my project, but when I send it for another person, they got the error:facebookSDK.h not found. The way to solved it, as far as I know is: **remove the facebook sdk and add it again**. But I just want to know the right way to add the facebook SDK into project, and then when send it for another person, they will build OK, don't need to do the above step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. I resolved this by changing the header search path to `./**`

Header search path of the facebook SDK you given as absolute  path so that you are facing this issue. You can either use the path relative to the project or `./**` also will be a fix

Comment: I have plus question that: will it work when the computer(which receive my project) had not install facebook SDK?

Comment: No. It will not work if its found the facebook SDK within the root folder.   `./**` tell the copiler to search all files within the project root folder

Answer (score 0):

I changed the path in the Build Settings (Framework Search Paths) to be `~/Documents/FacebookSDK` and since then it works smoothly on my computer and my partner's computer.